# How do I include a facebook page like button within a shared link on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Facebook share buttons have things like the "Author" you can add to it. What I'm trying to do is put the a like button to the page. I've seen this before a couple of times, unfortunately I didn't get a screenshot, and it's so rare I can't find one, but I know it exists. Here is where it would appear

[shared link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFhp9.png)

Does anyone know how to do this? The meta I need to do it?

Comment: I found an example 
http://i.imgur.com/JmZhs6V.png

Comment: Pretty sure that needs the `article:publisher` meta tag set. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/article/